# How to archive an online article

Tags: org-mode

Often times I find an interesting article online that I want to read later but I have a different priorities so I just paste a link into my org notes. Later these links become broken, and the articles are lost forever.

What I found works pretty well is to use https://archive.org/web/ to preserve online articles for later use. To save an article we just use the form on the bottom of the page. After a moment the link is ready.

I wish to simplify this process by just converting link at the point to archived one. The archiving is not guaranteed, though. Some of the websites don't allow crawlers and for the archive.org this is a must - "Only available for sites that allow crawlers."

Does anyone of you managed to implement such a solution?

I consider alternative solutions like downloading the page with the images into separate folder - most often I use w3m to read these articles, but not all of them may be opened in no-JS browser and I wish to have solution that will work even then.

Answer (score 1):

The following package provides an excellent solution and is easy to set up:

```
org-web-tools

(require 'org-web-tools)
(bind-key "C-x w" 'org-web-tools-read-url-as-org)
```

https://github.com/alphapapa/org-web-tools

Comment: Could you add a URL?

Answer (score 0):

After testing one of suggested solution I decided to create my own package which function that converts link at point to archive.org processed link.

It's available here: https://github.com/farynaio/org-url-archive